# Passing jquery JSON from Codeigniter controller to view

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I've been struggling  to make it work, but cannot pass the inserted data from the controler to the view in CI using JSON. The input value from the form is successfully inserted into the database, but cannot make it appear in the view.

This is my view file **ajax_view.php**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#submit").click(function(){

    var inp = $('#inp').val();


    $.post("ajax/ajax_input", { 'send' : inp },
       function(data){
            alert(data.input_text);

       }, "json");

});

});
</script>
   </head>
<body>
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
 <label for="inp">Text</label>
 <input type="text" name="inp" id="inp" />
 <label for="submit"></label>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```

And this is the **ajax_input** method of the **ajax.php** controller:

```
<?php
// Initializing controller .....
// .............................


 //ajax method
function ajax_input(){
    $var_1 = trim($this->input->post('send'));
    $array = array('input_text' => $var_1);

    echo json_encode($array);
    $this->db->insert('ajax',$array);
}
```

Trying to debug it with Firebug, it gives me that **data.input_text** is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I'm using XAMPP on Win, so is it posible that json configuration is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code itself should work, here are some tip:

1. I don't know if this is a typo or not, but your JS in not opened properly (missing `<script type="text/javascript">`)
2. use `submit()` event instead of having `click()` event on your submit input:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#form1").submit(function(){
               var inp = $('#inp').val();
               $.post("ajax/ajax_input/", { 'send' : inp },
               function(data){
                   console.log(data.input_text);
               }, 'json');
               return false;
           });
       });
   </script>
   ```
3. switch the two line in your Controller and return the `insert()` to a variable just in case:

   ```
   if($this->db->insert('ajax',$array))
       echo json_encode($array);
   else
       //echo json_encode(array("input_text"=>"Input was not inserted correctly!"));
       echo json_encode(array("input_text"=>$this->db->last_query())); // for testing purposes ONLY!! don't use in live website!
   ```

Comment: missing <script... > tag is typo. And yet no progress even with those changes. This is getting really strange. If I switch the lines above, I don't have any database input.

Comment: @dede: this should post the insert query on failure, copy it and try to insert it manually (using phpMyAdmin?) and see what happens!

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in you ajax_input.php page.
Change:
$array = array('**input_tekst**' => $var_1);
to

```
$array = array('input_text' => $var_1);
```

Comment: Just noticed the typo, and corrected it. I still cannot alert the value

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('input_tekst' => $var_1); //why tekst?
```

Change tekst to text.